# With what order does OpenCart executes vQmod xml files?

Tags: opencart, vqmod

If there are 2 vQmods `/vqmod/xml/mymod1.xml` & `/vqmod/xml/mymod2.xml` to change a file (for example) `catalog/model/tool/image.php`, which vQmod will be executed first in an OpenCart installation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vQmod loads and executes the xml files in alphabetical order. So for your example `/vqmod/xml/mymod1.xml` will be loaded and executed first, followed by `/vqmod/xml/mymod2.xml`